# Iteration over const collections in D

Tags: iterator, constants, d

In C++ (STL), we define const and non-const methods and two kinds of iterators for iteration over collection:

```cpp
class Container
{
    public:
    iterator begin();
    const_iterator begin() const;
};
```

How we can extend this technique to D? My first attempt:

```d
class Container(T) {
    class Range {
        ref T front();
        // implementation
    }

    class ConstRange {
        T front() const;
        // implementation
    }

    Range all() {
        return new Range(/**/);
    }

    ConstRange all() const {
        return new ConstRange(/**/);
    }
}

unittest {
    alias list = List!int;
    const list L = new list;
    writeln(L.all());
}
```

But it failed. I have an error:

`Error: nested type List.List!int.List.Range should have the same or weaker constancy as enclosing type const(List!int)`

What's wrong?

Comment: Const iterators? Is this even a thing in D?

Comment: @sigod, no, but troubles is not in it) There are no "const ranges" in D, but iteration over const containers must work correctly and method `front` should return not `ref T`. Even if it not a "D-way"

Comment: [`std.array.d` makes the range external](https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/phobos/blob/master/std/container/array.d) (remember that `private` if at the file/module level instead of the class level)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is to make your range exist outside the container, but still reference it. If the range is inside the container, it is subject to the transitive const rule, but if it is outside you can keep a const reference while being a mutable range. If you define them in the same file, the range can still see private members of the container.

Observe:

```d
class Container(T) {
        private T[] contents;

        this(T[] contents) {
                this.contents = contents;
        }

        RangeOver!(Container!T, T) getRange() {
                return RangeOver!(Container!T, T)(this);
        }
        RangeOver!(const(Container!T), const(T)) getRange() const {
                return RangeOver!(const(Container!T), const(T))(this);
        }
}

struct RangeOver(Container, T) {
        Container container;
        size_t iterationPosition;
        this(Container container) {
                this.container = container;
                this.iterationPosition = 0;
        }

        ref T front() {
                return container.contents[iterationPosition];
        }

        bool empty() {
                return iterationPosition == container.contents.length;
        }

        void popFront() {
                iterationPosition++;
        }
}


void main() {
        import std.stdio;

        // mutable iteration
        {
                writeln("about to mutate...");
                auto container = new Container!int([1,2,3]);
                foreach(ref item; container.getRange()) {
                        writeln(item);
                        item += 5;
                }
                writeln("mutation done");
                // changes seen
                foreach(item; container.getRange())
                        writeln(item);
        }

        // const iteration
        {
                writeln("consting it up y0");
                const container = new Container!int([1,2,3]);
                // allowed
                foreach(item; container.getRange())
                        writeln(item);
        }
}
```

Comment: Very thanks. I forgot that in D `const` is transitive.